# How to read Excel sheet names in Go?

Tags: go, excelize

I am using [`qax-os/excelize`](https://github.com/qax-os/excelize) to read Excel files in Go.

Is there a way to read sheet names in an Excel file?

Comment: Have you tried either of the GetSheetMap or GetSheetList functions?

Answer (score 1):

you can use in version v2:

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/xuri/excelize/v2#File.GetSheetList

or in v1 and v2:

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/xuri/excelize#File.GetSheetMap